# Heroku: ErrorTimeout connecting to a socket

Tags: python, sockets, heroku

I'm having problems with a simple socket connection to an Heroku app.

This is my server:

```
import socket
import os
import time 
import sys

server = socket.socket()
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 12344))
host = "0.0.0.0"
server.bind((host, port))
print(f"###### SERVER RUNNING ON PORT {port} ({host}) ######")
server.listen()

while True:

    s, addr = server.accept()
    print("Recived request from:", addr)
    
    print(addr, " sent: ", repr(s.recv(1024)))
    
    print("Answering to:", addr)

    s.send("Hello, world! (from server)".encode())
    
    print("Answered to:", addr)

    s.close()
```

It builds and run perfectly on Heroku(it receives also socket connection, not from me...by at this time, I don't care much about it)

This is my client:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = 'app_name.herokuapp.com/'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = int(sys.argv[1])            # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    print("connecting to " + HOST +":"+str(PORT))
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print(s)
    s.sendall("HI!!!".encode())
    data = s.recv(1024)

print('Received', repr(data))
```

Running the client, after a while it returns:

```
  File "./client.py", line 14, in <module>
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

I don't know how to connect to it...am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is linked to the fact that Heroku app allow only http(s) connections. I honesty didn't found any Heroku docs that conferm it but the Daniel Chin' answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600814/deploying-a-tcp-server-to-heroku) question make sense to me.

However, move the server.py to AWS worked for me (EC2 with t2.micro is free for the first year!!)